# Display battery usage

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, screen

Is this okay, or is it too much for screen to use this much battery? Screen brightness is on minimum (not on auto) and screen timeout is 30 seconds. In this example screen was awake for 3h 20m.

[image]

Comment: Seems to be fine

Comment: @beeshyams Hmm, ok thanks. I tought there might be a problem because as you see for 3h of using battery dropped from 100% to 17%, is that normal too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior. The display is still the most power hungry component of any smartphone.